# how to fix "Failed to create session in appium inspector

Tags: android, appium, robotframework, appium-inspector

anyone can help me for the issue when create start session in appium inspector

how to fix "Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.example.demo' application". Thank you

can fix my appium inspector issue

Answer (score 0):

Start appium server using command appium -p 4723
or start Appium desktop